# MSISDN header not set for apache

Tags: php, apache, http-headers

I want to detect user's mobile number who is visiting my site. I tried to print all the request headers in http://embarsar.com/testing/headers.php. I can't find any of MSISDN header in it. I tried in IDEA,AIRTEL,JIO,VODAFONE. No network giving this header. I used http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php to get all the headers